# Where can I find bunzip (not bunzip2)?

Tags: 14.04, bzip2

I have an old bzip file that I need to unpack. However, I can only seem to find bunzip2, which does not read this bzip file.

I have not been able to find any program that handles bzip files. Is there really nothing modern that can read such a file?

Comment: Are you sure the bzip file hasn't been corrupted, or otherwise rendered invalid? What's the error that bzip2 gives?

Comment: "bunzip2 report.ps.bz" gives the output "bunzip2: report.ps.bz is not a bzip2 file."
And Ark says that the bz file contains a 0-byte file called report.ps.bz.uncompressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [bzip2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2#cite_note-3) links to the an archived copy of the homepage for explaining the switch from `bzip` to `bzip2`. A subsequent section reads:

> #### How can I decompress old .bz files (created by bzip-0.21) ?
>
> Here's a [the source code](https://web.archive.org/web/19980704181646/http://www.muraroa.demon.co.uk/bunzip021.c) for a decompress-only version of
>   bzip-0.21.  Or you can download a binary for [Linux-ELF](https://web.archive.org/web/19980704181204/http://www.muraroa.demon.co.uk/bunzip021-linuxelf).

The code compiled fine on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You're a life saver! There it is!